# Site crashes if I try to export products in csv format

Tags: performance, magento, export-to-csv

I am using magento 1.7.0.2 CE.

I have 28000 products in my catalog.I am using "*Custom Bulk Product Import + Export with Tier Pricing / Product Custom Options / Configurable Products / Bundle Products / Grouped Products / Downloadable*"  extension to export/import products.

There is an option in dataflow advanced profile to limit the number of records to export.

Even if I export 500 record the site crashes.
Varnish is configured on my server.I get *Guru meditation* error in forntend.

I contacted the extension provider , they say this is a server issue not the extension issue.

How can I configure my server properly. So that I can export at least 1000 records(at a time)?

Please suggest.

I have following in php.ini

```
mysql.connect_timeout = 60

max_execution_time  300000
```

Comment: How much memory do you have configured to use per apache process and how much ram is on the actual server. My bet is server is running out of resources. Check apache error log and magento exception and system logs for errors.

Comment: @AshleySwatton server ram is 8GB, this is dedicated server, I think I am facing this because of some improper configuration.

Comment: Ok 8gb on the server and what is apache setup to use per process? Try increasing this value whatever it is. .htaccess file has a memory config value as well. To rule out varnish, why not disable it and try to do the export. If it works, then it's related to varnish, if not then its a red herring. How can I configure my server properly is a very broad question for a large complex topic and always depends on your unique setup. Please check all magento logs (exception and system) and apache logs for actual errors as soon as it fails, and post back and someone might be able to help you.

Comment: This was a happening because of some server issue related to varnish.It is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Muk the server is having time out issues, increase the maximum execution time or timeout on your server and it should work properly.

Comment: I have max_execution_time 300000  visible, seen using phpinfo().

Comment: Check the error_log on your server and what is Magento error outputting as well ?

Comment: Check your memory limits.